# Own Maven Plugin Property marked as "Element .. is not allowd here" in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I created an own maven plugin:

```
@Mojo(name = "build")
public class InstallerBuilder extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(property = "installerBuilderApplication", required = true)
    private File installerBuilderApplication;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {

        getLog().info("installerBuilderApplication: " + installerBuilderApplication);

        if (!installerBuilderApplication.isFile()) {
            getLog().error("Please ceheck [installerBuilderApplication] argument is correct.");
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Application for installer builder is not a file [" + installerBuilderApplication.getName() + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using it in other maven project like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>company-installer</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.company.lsg</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>lsg-installer-builder</artifactId>
    <name>LSG Installer and Patches Build</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.company.lsg</groupId>
                <artifactId>lsg-installer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <installerBuilderApplication>${basedir}/src/installer/builder_app/NSISPortable/App/NSIS/makensis.exe</installerBuilderApplication>
                    <installerBase>C:\LSG\Generic_Installer</installerBase>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- inherits config from parent: can override if required -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Where the paramter is marked:
[image]

Maven package works, but it somehow bothers me.

Could anyone suggest what I could do to overcome the error!

EDIT: I added the whole pom.xml it is a module of parent. Parent has just three modules declared and pluginmanagement with maven-compile-plugin

Comment: Can you show the beginning of the pom.xml file?

Comment: I added the wohle pom.xml

Comment: Make sure the plugin can be resolved from the Editor, that the version is specified. Try updating [maven repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-repositories.html) indices.

Comment: The plugin works (at least it fails if I do not provide the parameter). I did: Settings->..->Maven->Repositories->Update, but this did not help either